# Morris js with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, node-modules, morris.js

I try to display my data as a morris bar chart.But im new with nodejs and morris so i really dont know how to do it.

I write a function that return my data as string

```
   for(i=0; i<l; i++)
    {
    var mesure_Valeur = JSON.parse(mesures[i]);

      data=data+"{date: "+mesure_Valeur.date
        +", p1: "+mesure_Valeur.p1
        +", p2: "+mesure_Valeur.p2+"},";
  } 
   data=data.substr(0,data.length-1);
    data=data+"]";
    datas=data.toString();
```

my function return datas. After that i tried to use morris but i did not undrestand how can i get the Xkey and data from my datas.
Can anyone help me please?

```
 <script>


 Morris.Bar({
 element: 'bar-example',
 data:('data'),
 xkey: 'date',
 ykeys: ['energiep1'],
 labels: ['Series A', 'Series B']
  });
  </script>
```

Do you have any idea please?? thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Morris documentation](https://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/bars.html), Morris expects `data` to be an array of objects, where each object represents one data point and has attributes for x- and y-values. Since it looks like your source data is already stored in `mesures` as a well-formed JSON object, there is no need to convert it to a string. The following code should work:

```
Morris.Bar({
  element: 'bar-example',
  data: mesures,
  xkey: 'date',
  ykeys: ['p1', 'p2'],
  labels: ['Series A', 'Series B']
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But this solution did not work.